# How to make Inkscape remember its previous window size?

Tags: inkscape

Every time I start Inkscape, no matter what, it starts up in an unusably small window.

[image]

Each and every other program I use remembers its window size. Why won't Inkscape? Is there a way to force Inkscape to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Open up the inkscape preferences (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and find the `Windows` section.
2. Select the `Remember and use last window's geometry` option:
   [image]